# Why can tf.image.decode_jpeg decode a png?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow

Today I was testing some tensorflow (python) codes. It's a neural network on the famous MNIST set.

Everything worked well, so I just read through the codes and studied the structure of that network.

When it came to the image input, I found the following code:

```
image_string = tf.read_file(filename)

image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)
```

The code is using "decode_jpeg" instead of "decode_png". And I didn't see any error.

However, I am 100% sure that the images are in PNG format.

I have used

```
od -c -b 1.png
```

to  look into those images and they are PNGs.

**So, why could "decode_jpeg" work on PNGs ? And is there any potential issue that might be caused by this?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [documentation for tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/decode_jpeg) states:

> This op also supports decoding PNGs and non-animated GIFs since the interface is the same, though it is cleaner to use tf.image.decode_image.

So essentially it was a design decision that because the interface is the same to just handle it, rather than throw an error that forces user to use the correct API call.

Comment: Very interesting design decision. I would challenge whether it is really cleaner to use `decode_image`. The output shape from that function is unpredictable: `Tensor with type dtype and a 3- or 4-dimensional shape, depending on the file type and the value of the expand_animations parameter.`

Comment: Are the results exactly equal? I think it must at least throw warnings.

Answer (score 0):

```
img = tf.image.decode_png(file_bytes, channels=3)
```

you can use `decode_png` for png files

Comment: OP is aware of `decode_png`, he mentioned it in the question. The question is "why does `decode_jpeg` works?".